# Encrypting a Ser File in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to encrypt (and then decrypt) a serialized backup using a password that gets typed in by the user.

I have looked in the documentation but I'm fairly new to VB and can't get my head round it, so if possible could someone please explain how I do this?

Here's the serialization sub:

```
Private Sub BackupAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackupAllToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
    Dim backupFile As New FileStream(fldSerBackup & Strings.Replace(Strings.Replace(Now, ":", "_"), "/", ".") & ".ser", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    formatter.Serialize(backupFile, photoJobs)
    backupFile.Close()
    MsgBox("Collection saved to file")
End Sub
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: if you are serializing something, presumably to a stream, you might be able to use a [CryptoStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx) and save a step or two

Comment: The link explains *everything* about them and include sample/demo code.  They essentially wrap other streams to encrypt the contents

Comment: Ohh I didn't spot the link, thought it was just formatting it because its  a type... thanks!